# html+css double pull down menu

Tags: html, css

I would like to create double Pull Down Menus and I used html+css. The ideal menu should like this: when mouse hover on "People" , then the first pull down menu occured , which inclued "Presenter" "Staff" and "Student" . And then mouse hover on the "Presenter" will occur the second pull down menu "PresenterA" , hover on the "Staff" will occur the second pull down menu "StaffA" "StaffB" "StaffC".  The problem is that: I did the first pull down menu , its ok , but when i did the second pull down menu , problems occured. I tried again and again , but it still be wrong . I think the .popup and .popupli in css have some problems , please help me to solve this problem , how to change the css ? thanks a lot!

html:

```
<li class="{% if page.author %}current{% endif %}">
    <a href="/news/">People</a>
    <ul>
      <div class="popup">
       <li><a href="#">Presenter</a></li>
          <ul>
            <div class="popupli">
              <li><a href="#">PresenterA</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
       <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
          <ul>
            <div class="popupli">
              <li><a href="#">StaffA</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">StaffB</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">StaffC</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
       <li><a href="#">Student</a></li>
          <ul>
            <div class="popupli">
              <li><a href="#">Student1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Student2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Student3</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </li>

css:
li { display: inline-block; }
  li:hover .popup
  {
       display:block;
  }
/*  li :hover .popupli
  {
       display:block;
  } */
  .popup
     {
        display:none;
    text-align:left;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    width:8em;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 0.0em;
        li:hover .popupli
        {
            display:block;
        }
     }
   .popupli
     {
        display:none;
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    width:8em;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 0.0em;
     }
```

Comment: sounds like an accordion menu.

Comment: I thought this tutorial was great: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu long as you only want to support CSS3 this should do. (Works with IE9)

Answer (score 0):

I had solved problems after I looked up to the website:line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu which Tim answered. The website is great and just solved what I ask . Thanks a lot!

I used > attribute in css to solve my problem and some of my origin code are wrong.